# How to slide up or down ul elements based on selected item

Tags: jquery, menu, accordion, selected

I have the following menu for an application I am building and I'm having a hard time applying some jquery rules to hide the subcategories of the menu.

What I want to do is as follows:

When I first load the page, I want the children( child1, child2 etc) of each category to slide up (close). Through code, I keep track of the selected item so if I load a different page, the menu should be build according to the following rule:

If I apply a class "selected"  to, say, Category1, then I want its children to slide down. If the class "selected" is applied to a child, then I want its parent ul to be expanded also.

Case 1: selected class applied to Category1

```
<ul>     
<li class="selected has-children first-child">Category1</a>                       
 <ul>
  <li class="first-child">Child1</li>
  <li class=" ">Child2</li>
  <li class=" ">Child3</li>
  <li class=" ">Child4</li>
  <li class=" ">Child5></li>
  <li class=" ">Child6</li>
  <li class="last-child">Child6</li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li class="has-children">Category2</a>
 <ul>
  <li class="first-child">Child1</li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li class="has-children last-child">Category3</a>
 <ul>
  <li class="first-child">Child1</li>
  <li class="last-child">Child2</li>
 </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

---

```
Case 2: selected class applied to child4 (ul should be expanded)

<ul>     
<li class="selected has-children first-child">Category1</a>                       
 <ul>
  <li class="first-child">Child1</li>
  <li class=" ">Child2</li>
  <li class=" ">Child3</li>
  <li class="selected ">Child4</li>
  <li class=" ">Child5></li>
  <li class=" ">Child6</li>
  <li class="last-child">Child6</li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li class="has-children">Category2</a>
 <ul>
  <li class="first-child">Child1</li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li class="has-children last-child">Category3</a>
 <ul>
  <li class="first-child">Child1</li>
  <li class="last-child">Child2</li>
 </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Τhank  you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want any interactivity with expanding/collapsing these menus?  Or do you just want to apply this functionality once on pageload?  If it's the second, then you need to define class names:

```
li.parent {
   display:none;
}

li.selected {
   display:block;
}
```

You need to apply this class name to all parent elements.  Any parent elements which have the class name `selected` will automatically show their child elements.  Then, using this jQuery:

```
$(function() {

   $('li.parent li').each(function() {
      var parent = $(this).parent('ul').parent('li');
      if($(this).hasClass('selected') || parent.hasClass('selected')) {
         parent.show();
      }
   });

});
```

This loops through every li child element and checks whether it has the class name `selected`. If it does, it shows the parent li.

Comment: Thank you. I am almost there. I have replaced the class li.parent by li.has-children to fit more into the code I use. But, when I apply a class selected to a child, nothing shows. Take a look at this here: http://jsbin.com/ititir/6/edit